# switch function and object with scalaz' |>

Tags: scala, scalaz

I can use `scalaz` `|>` operator when I want to switch function and object so there can be a little more readability acquired. Let me introduce you a model function :

```
def length2(x:String) = x.length * 2
```

Now, I can write it in both ways:

```
"aoeu" |> length2
length2("aoeu")
```

But if I define this function more generic, it stops working.

```
def length2(x:SeqLike[_,_]) = x.length * 2
length2("aoeu") // ok
"aoeu" |> length2 // doesn't work
```

Why the compiler doesn't understand this? There is definitely an implicit conversion from `String` to some class mixing in trait `SeqLike`.

Comment: Tricky. At first I thought it’s because you can only have one implicit at a time but now it seems it is maybe also a variance issue hidden somewhere…

Comment: @Debilski, I'm not sure where `|>` is defined in scalaz, but when I tried to define my own, I think the "only one implicit rule" is what prevented it from applying: "aoeu" would need to be implicitly converted to the class with the `|>` method and then again to `SeqLike`.

Comment: Show the error message. Not everyone has Scalaz readily available, but error messages usually explain what's going wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scala> "aoeu" |> length2
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scala.collection.SeqLike[_, _]) => Int
 required: (java.lang.String) => ?
       "aoeu" |> length2
```

The error message is pretty clear.

Although there is an implicit conversion from `String` to `SeqLike[_,_]`, there is no conversion from `(SeqLike[_, _]) => Int` to `String => ?`.

This can be fixed using the following implicit conversion:

```
implicit def liftFun[X, T <% X, U](f: (X) => U): (T) => U = {
  def g(t:T) = f(t)
  g _
}
```

*Edit 2*: here is a non-scalaz operator.

```
class Pipe[T](t:T) {
  def |%>[X, U](f: (X) => U)(implicit ev: T <%< X) = f(t)
}
implicit def toPipe[T](t:T) = new Pipe(t:T)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
def l1(a:String) = a.length
def l2(a:Seq[_]) = a.length * 2

"abc" |%> l1
"abc" |%> l2
```

It allows `|%>` to take a function that does not work directly on a `T` but on a `X` as long as there is evidence of an implicit conversion from `T` to `X`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use existential types unless necessary. They break things, and are not required here.

On the other hand, seeing in the error in the other answer made things more clear. You there are two implicit conversions being asked for when you use `|>`. Does it work if you declare it like this instead:

```
def length2[CC <% SeqLike[_, _]](x: CC) = x.length * 2
```

Comment: This returns: `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type (CC) => scala.collection.SeqLike[_, _]`