# Is there a Scala operator similar to Haskell's $ (dollar sign)?

Tags: scala, operators

Is there any way to force operator precedence in Scala like you do in Haskell with $?

For example, in Haskell, you have:

```
a b c = ((a b) c)
```

and

```
a $ b c = a (b c)
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Scala? I know Scala doesn't have operators per se, but is there a way to achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

infix vs . notation is often used in a similar fashion to control precedence:

```
a b c d == a.b(c).d
a.b c d == a.b.c(d)
a b c.d == a.b(c.d)
```

Scala also has a fixed precedence ordering for operators used in infix notation:

```
(all letters)
|
^
&
< >
= !
:
+ -
* / %
(all other special characters)
```

Names can usually chosen explicitly to take advantage of this.  For example, `~` and `^^` in the standard parsers library.

Comment: Pursued again by the phantom downvoter who leaves no explanation... most bizarre

Comment: lovely code snippet that first one - i'll keep that handy to remind myself of these rules. thanks

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to use implicits to achieve a similar effect. For example:
(untested, but should be something like this)

```
object Operator {

  class WithOperator[T](that: T) {
    def &:[U](f: T => U) = f(that)
  }
  implicit def withOperator[T](that: T) = new WithOperator(that)

}
```

Using this system, you can't use the name $, because the name needs to end with a : (to fix the associativity) and the dollar is a normal identifier (not operator identifier), so you can't have it in the same name as a :, unless you separate them with underscores.

So, how do you use them? Like this:

```
val plusOne = (x: Int) => {x + 1}
plusOne &: plusOne &: plusOne &: 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Scalaz has defined a "pipe" operator, which works similar, but with flipped arguments. See [switch function and object with scalaz' |>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699767/switch-function-and-object-with-scalaz)