# Precedence operators in Ruby from Haskell?

Tags: ruby

```
(max 23,23) == (max 23,23)
```

In above example I must put parenthesis over both  methods. Is there something similar to Haskell's precedence operator: [`dollar($)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843010/is-there-a-scala-operator-similar-to-haskells-dollar-sign) so I can write something like this:

```
(max 2,3) == $ max 2,2
```

Or like this:

```
$ max 2,3 == $ max 2,3
```

and both examples evaluate to first example?

Or is there something that give me power over precedence in Ruby, like some keyword in method definition?

Comment: Replace `$` with `(` and add `)` at the end of the scope. After all, they are the same thing. They are not really different unless you look into something like TeX's `\expandafter`.

Comment: How this '\expandafter' works?

Comment: @DarekNędza http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/expandafter

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence is not modifiable. Use parens if you want to change default precedence.

The issue is in the parser (assuming you're defining `max` with a splatted param); Ruby's liberal whitespace policies can create issues when it's not clear how something should be parsed.

Comment: +1. And not to mention, I think `(max 23, 23) == (max 23, 23)`, or `max(23,23) == max(23,23)` is, on sight, clearer in intent than something like `$ max 23,23 == $ max 23,23` anyway. :)

Comment: Actually, they are almost the same. The only difference is that `$` only shows one end of the part with priority, so it cannot be used for infix operators.

Comment: `max` is just method that takes 2 args  
@mbratch in this simple example you are right - it's 'clearer' but when you have multiple methods, so it ends like `))))` you know it will be 'ugly'.

Comment: @DarekNędza It's still the same precedence issue, though. IMO parens for precedence, particularly in deeply-nested expressions, will always win a clarity contest with isolated `$`.